# R - How to create a loop which bases its function on a previous value in a column without specifying exactly what this value is

Tags: r, loops, populate

I am trying to predict population numbers for every country in the world. I want to do this by using the previous year population and multiplying it by the predicted growth for the current year. Because I will have multiple countries in the dataframe I want the code to identify the last population for Afghanistan for example, rather than going off the previous row, which could be another country like Bangladesh for example.

The ALL_DATA is my data frame and contains the below columns

```
Country - AFG
Code - AFG_2016
Population - 200000
Growth - 0.0002
```

I have tried ordering the data and using the below loop, however, it struggles ordering the data with multiple countries and years with NAs.

```
ALL_DATA[order(ALL_DATA$Code) 

index<-min(which(is.na(ALL_DATA$Population)))
for(i in index:dim(ALL_DATA[1])){ALL_DATA$Population[i]<-(ALL_DATA$Population[i-1]*(1+ALL_DATA$Growth[i]))
}
```

Thanks for your help, let me know if you require anymore information

Comment: hi! if this data already exists in form of columns, why not just use te apply-function? from what i understand, you already have all the necessary informations as columns in a data frame so something like `results<-apply(your_df, 1, FUN= function(x) df$Population *df$Growth )`

Comment: Thanks for the above, I just tried it and it din't quite give me what I wanted. I want to be able to replace the NAs in the same dataframe, as those values will be needed in the coding later. Additionally the ordering doesn't seem to work so thought there may be an option to get R to identify previous country value but can't seem to work it out! Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Use `Reduce` together with a group-by-apply approach (e.g., as implemented in data.table or dplyr).

Comment: in that case, it would be great if you could give an actual (short) example of the data frame you have. `head(your_df)` would do, and a (similarly abbreviated) result data frame for better visualization of how you want the data to look like.

Comment: "Country PCP     Code Year LR_P     SR_P     P_P ON_LR ON_SR ON_P
1     GEO   2 GEO_2016 2016   25 340000.0 2000000   500   200   10
2     GEO   2 GEO_2017 2017   30 390000.0  250000   300  3000   10
3     GEO   2 GEO_2018 2018   40 400000.0 3000000   400   500    5
4     GEO   3 GEO_2019 2019   NA 414563.7      NA    NA    NA   NA
5     GEO   3 GEO_2020 2020   NA 429657.6      NA    NA    NA   NA"
Ignore last columns - LR_P is large ruminant population. It would have other countries in there too. I want to replace the NAs with the previous year population of that country*growth

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it on here to make it look like it does in R!